# Why does Stanford dcoref stop throwing warnings on bad text when 2 Stanford NLP pipelines are created?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.1 with the SR parser model.

When running the code below, the dcoref annotator logs warnings in the method "try1", but not in "try2", when another (unused) pipeline is created in the same scope.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

public class NLPBug {
static String badText = "Colonial Williamsburg A historical researcher has compiled beauty tips from the time and created a hog's lard moisturizer.";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties p1 = new Properties();
    p1.put("annotators",
            "tokenize, ssplit, cleanxml, pos, lemma, ner, entitymentions, parse, dcoref");
    p1.put("parse.model",
            "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");

    Properties p2 = new Properties();
    p2.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");

    try1(p1);
    try2(p1, p2);
}

public static void try1(Properties p1) {
    StanfordCoreNLP nlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(p1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Annotating (1)...");
    nlp.process(badText);
    System.out.print("Done");
}

public static void try2(Properties p1, Properties p2) {
    StanfordCoreNLP nlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(p1);
    StanfordCoreNLP notUsed = new StanfordCoreNLP(p2);
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("Annotating (2)");
    nlp.process(badText);
    System.out.println("Done...");
}

}
```

The warnings "RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder: Failed to find head token", "RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder: Last resort: returning as head: moisturizer" occur only in try1. What is the reason for this behaviour and is there any way to fix these warnings?